# Invoking an endpoint in AWS with a multidimensional array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a Tensorflow-Model in SageMaker Studio following this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-trained-keras-or-tensorflow-models-using-amazon-sagemaker/
The Model needs a Multidimensional Array as input. Invoking it from the Notebook itself is working:

```
import numpy as np
import json
data = np.load("testValues.npy")
pred=predictor.predict(data)
```

But I wasnt able to invoke it from a boto 3 client using this code:

```
import json
import boto3
import numpy as np
import io
 
client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
datain = np.load("testValues.npy")
data=datain.tolist();
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, Body=json.dumps(data))
response_body = response['Body']
print(response_body.read())
```

This throws the Error:

```
An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "{"error": "Unsupported Media Type: Unknown"}".
```

I guess the reason is the json Media Type but i have no clue how to get it back in shape.
I tried this:https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/644 but it doesnt seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me:
The Content Type was missing.

```
import json
import boto3
import numpy as np
import io

client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker',aws_access_key_id=..., aws_secret_access_key=...,region_name=...)
endpoint_name = '...'

data = np.load("testValues.npy")


payload = json.dumps(data.tolist())
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                                  ContentType='application/json',
                                   Body=payload)
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
res = result['predictions']
print("test")
```